# how can we get the result from various actors and then send the result from all the actors to one response in play 2.2.0?

Tags: scala, akka, play2-mini

```
case object getValues
case class Data(a: Any, b:Any)

class Testing extends Actor {
def receive = {
case "do something" => {
  val result2 = { User.getList }
  sender ! result2
}
case _ => println("done")
}
}

class Testing2 extends Actor {
def receive = {
case getValues =>
  val result2 = { User.getMap }
   }yield Data(a,b)
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[Testing], "child")//creating actor
  implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(1.second)//giving timeout
  val r = child ? "do something"
  val res = for {
    a <- r
  } yield (a)
  res map (p=>sender ! Data(p, result2))//sending response to the sender
}
}

//Controller
object Application extends Controller {

def testingActor2 = Action.async {
val system = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[Testing2], "Testing2")
implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(1.second)
val res = actor1 ? getValues
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val result = for {
  r1 <- res
} yield r1
result map (r => { println(r); Ok("got result") })
}
```

i am not able to get the result of both actors to controller. Please tell me how to use actors if i have to take their result and then send with the response to the page .

Answer (score 3):

```
val f1 = Future(1) //ask first actor
  val f2 = Future(2) //ask second actor

  Future.sequence(List(f1, f2)).map(list => {
    //we got List[Int] here
    list
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue I can see with your code, and it might not be the entire problem, is that in `Testing2`, you are closing over the `sender` which is mutable and can lead to issues.  The reason is that by the time the async `map` is run on the `Future`, the `sender` could have changed to a different `ActorRef` or could be nullified (switched to the dead letter actor ref) either way you won't get the response back to where you intended for it to go.  You can fix that simply by doing the following:

```
...
val res = for {
  a <- r
} yield (a)
val originator = sender
res foreach (p=>originator ! Data(p, result2))//sending response to the sender
```

Or you could import the `pipeTo` pattern and do it like this:

```
import akka.pattern.pipeTo
...
val res = for {
  a <- r
} yield (a)
res map (p=> Data(p, result2)) pipeTo sender
```